# React components library with tailwind and obfuscated class names

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

im building a components library to use internally in my company by many other applications. Im currently using tailwind on the library to build the components, but the other applications may or may not use tailwind.

Im having an issue with those applications that use tailwind, because its like two instances of tailwind are installed on the final application and im experiencing some classes colission and some weird behaviours.

Is there any way i could modify the "rollup.config.js" file to compile class names to hashes?

Should i use styled-components or some css in js library?

I want to keep the styles of the components library on a external css file for performance and SEO improves.

Comment: Component library + Tailwind sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Do you think css modules is better? Or styled components? Or what would you use?

Comment: Anything besides Tailwind or global style sheets.